# Changing a single client server into a multiple server c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets, serversocket

Okay so I have ran into a problem, I have created a server which handles a single client and now I want to kick it up a notch and have it handle multiple clients at one time.
I have looked and tried to do this using HashTables and also Async but I keep getting stuck, this is a grey area for me as I have only just recently started dealing with sockets etc...
I wondered if anyone had a way of doing it? 
Any advise will be taken on board.
This is my server code(If it helps).

```
namespace ChatServer
{

    delegate void UpdateTextBox(string msg);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpListener ConnectionListener;
        private BinaryReader MessageReader;
        private BinaryWriter MessageWriter;
        private Socket ClientConnection;
        private NetworkStream DataStream;
        private Thread ListeningThread;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                IPAddress.Parse(textBox3.Text);//
                ListeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForConnections));
                ListeningThread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Ip Address");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ClientConnection.Connected)
                {
                    MessageWriter.Write(textBox2.Text);
                    textBox2.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no client is connected");
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {

                try
                {
                    if (ClientConnection.Connected)
                    {
                        MessageWriter.Write(textBox2.Text);
                        textBox2.Clear();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no client is connected");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
        }

        private void ListenForConnections()
        {

            try
            {
                ConnectionListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(textBox3.Text), 80);
                ConnectionListener.Start();
                ChangeTextBoxContent("Listening For Connections");
                ClientConnection = ConnectionListener.AcceptSocket(); 
                DataStream = new NetworkStream(ClientConnection);
                MessageReader = new BinaryReader(DataStream);
                MessageWriter = new BinaryWriter(DataStream);
                ChangeTextBoxContent("Connection Received");
                HandleConnection();
                MessageReader.Close();
                MessageWriter.Close();
                DataStream.Close();
                ClientConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect, wrong ip address");
            }
        }
        private void HandleConnection()
        {
            string message;

            do
            {

                try
                {
                    message = MessageReader.ReadString();
                    ChangeTextBoxContent(message);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ChangeTextBoxContent("connection Lost");
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
        }
        private void ChangeTextBoxContent(string tx)
        {
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new UpdateTextBox(ChangeTextBoxContent), new object[] { tx });
            }
            else
            {    
                textBox1.Text += tx + "\r\n";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle each of your connections in a separate thread. Create a loop that constantly listens for remote connections, and when a remote connection is called, create a new thread with the connection as the object parameter.